# Zero-width text node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a bunch of tikz pictures that will be aligned in `tabular` cells. These pictures are colored horizontal bars and at the location of color change I include a text node with a date. As you can see on the screen capture, when the text node is on the left border of the bar, its width is added to the width of the bar and when I try to align, my bar is pushed to the right:

[image]

This phenomenon occurs on bars 1, 3 and 5, while bars 2 and 4 are correctly aligned (flush left). I tried to use a `\clap` (the both-sides version of `\llap` and `\rlap`) but it didn't worked. Here is the tikz code to obtain the color bar:

```
\def\charly#1#2#3#4{\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=white,every path/.style={draw},scale=0.5]
\fill (0,0) rectangle (10,0.2);
\fill[color=red] (#1,0) rectangle (#2,0.2);
\fill[color=blue] (#2,0) rectangle (10,0.2);
\node (A) at (#1,-0.2) { \fontsize{6pt}{5pt}\selectfont\clap{#3} };
\node (B) at (#2,-0.2) { \fontsize{6pt}{5pt}\selectfont\clap{#4} };
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

and the code is then used as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Error&Correct&Interval of error occurrences\\\hline
dont (138)&don't (2)&\charly{0}{9.72972972972973}{3/3}{4/8}\\
dint (45)&didn't (2)&\charly{0.27027027027027}{9.72972972972973}{3/4}{4/8}\\
tolld (39)&told (43)&\charly{0}{1.08108108108108}{3/3}{3/7}\\
pepul (37)&people (10)&\charly{0.27027027027027}{1.08108108108108}{3/4}{3/7}\\
werk (31)&work (11)&\charly{0}{4.86486486486486}{3/3}{3/21}\\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I tell tikz not to take the text node into account when calculating the global width of the picture?

Comment: Try `\node[overlay] ...`. You can also use `\path[use as bounding box] <some universal path>`;` to have all bars share the same bounding box.

Comment: The `overlay` tip worked, thank you so much! This one of those simple things you can search for hours in the manual…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `overlay` key to exclude the node(s) form the bounding box. However, I personally would probably use `\path[use as bounding box] ...;` as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\charly[4]{\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=white,
    every path/.style={draw},scale=0.5,
    node font=\fontsize{6pt}{5pt}\selectfont
    ]
\path[use as bounding box,draw=none]    (-0.2,-0.2) rectangle (10,0.2);
\fill (0,0) rectangle (10,0.2);
\fill[color=red] (#1,0) rectangle (#2,0.2);
\fill[color=blue] (#2,0) rectangle (10,0.2);
\node (A) at (#1,-0.2) {#3};
\node (B) at (#2,-0.2) {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Error&Correct&Interval of error occurrences\\\hline
dont (138)&don't (2)&\charly{0}{9.72972972972973}{3/3}{4/8}\\
dint (45)&didn't (2)&\charly{0.27027027027027}{9.72972972972973}{3/4}{4/8}\\
tolld (39)&told (43)&\charly{0}{1.08108108108108}{3/3}{3/7}\\
pepul (37)&people (10)&\charly{0.27027027027027}{1.08108108108108}{3/4}{3/7}\\
werk (31)&work (11)&\charly{0}{4.86486486486486}{3/3}{3/21}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]